# How can i get the selected item of the listbox in C#.net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [listBox selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856238/listbox-selected-item)

i need to get the particular selected item of the list box which is sourced by a database column and insert the selected item into a new database.?
m working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server Express

```
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ItemName from tariff", con);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        this.listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
        con.Close();

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO logs VALUES('" + txtRoom.Text.ToString() + "','"????????????????????????????"')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        loadData();
    }
```

Comment: Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try

`listbox1.SelectedItem.Text`

Also: you are setting yourself up for possible [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should take a look at parametrized queries.

Using those would turn your statement into something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO logs VALUES(@room,@listbox)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room", txtRoom.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@listbox",listbox1.SelectedItem.Text);
```